# Doesn't see popup menu on combobox

Tags: qt, qml

I'm trying to set a new style to comboBox in qml and get in trouble my combobox doesn't want to show me drop-down list everything else is fine, here is code

The code I took from Internet

```
T.ComboBox {
      id: _comboBox
      anchors.bottom: _borderedTextboxPoints.top
      anchors.horizontalCenter: _borderedTextboxPoints.horizontalCenter
      anchors.bottomMargin: 10

      delegate: T.ItemDelegate {  //! Changing style of items in list
             width: _comboBox.width
             contentItem: Text {
                 text: modelData
                 color: "black"
                 font: _comboBox.font
                 elide: Text.ElideRight
                 verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
             }
             highlighted: _comboBox.highlightedIndex === index
         }

         indicator: Canvas {  //! Changing style of indicator
             id: canvas
             x: _comboBox.width - width - _comboBox.rightPadding - 5
             y: _comboBox.topPadding + (_comboBox.availableHeight - height) / 2
             width: 12
             height: 8
             contextType: "2d"

             Connections { //! Changing style on pressed
                 target: _comboBox
                 function onPressedChanged() { canvas.requestPaint(); }
             }

             onPaint: {
                 context.reset();
                 context.moveTo(0, 0);
                 context.lineTo(width, 0);
                 context.lineTo(width / 2, height);
                 context.closePath();
                 context.fillStyle = _comboBox.pressed ? "#722ed1" : "#531dab";
                 context.fill();
             }
         }

         contentItem: Text {
             leftPadding: 5
             rightPadding: _comboBox.indicator.width + _comboBox.spacing

             text: _comboBox.displayText
             font: _comboBox.font
             color: "black"
             verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
             elide: Text.ElideRight
         }

         background: Rectangle {
             implicitWidth: 120
             implicitHeight: 40
             border.color: _comboBox.pressed ? "#2f54eb" : "#1d39c4"
             border.width: _comboBox.visualFocus ? 2 : 1
             radius: 10
         }

         popup: T.Popup { //! Changing style of drop-down list
             y: _comboBox.height - 1
             width: _comboBox.width
             implicitHeight: contentItem.implicitHeight
             padding: 1

             contentItem: ListView {
                 clip: true
                 implicitHeight: contentHeight
                 model:_comboBox.popup.visible ? _comboBox.delegateModel : null
                 currentIndex: _comboBox.highlightedIndex

                T.ScrollIndicator.vertical: T.ScrollIndicator { }
             }
         }
      }
```

That's look like this

[image]

Comment: Don't you need some _onClick_ handling for the indicator item?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the popup code add a z and use an index higher than 1

```
popup: T.Popup { //! Changing style of drop-down list
         ...
         padding: 1
         z: 4
         ...
```

I used 4 as the z, here because I knew 4 will definitely work. But maybe 2 too would have worked.

This usually happens when you are showing the combo box in a popup.

Comment: The T namespace, if you don't have it declared as `import QtQuick.Controls 2.15 as T`, Kindly remove the T.